# How do you set an expiration for a celery chain?

Tags: celery

This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, so I'm a bit lost. I call my chain like:

```
chain(add.si(), multiply.s(4)).apply_async()
```

But sometimes workers are so backed up I want the task to expire and not be run. Is there a way to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Both expiration and ETA (estimated time of arrival) are nicely documented in [this section](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown). It applies to any Celery workflow just like with any "regular" task.

Comment: So just add `.apply_async(expires=200)` to a chain and we're off to the races? Too simple!